# How can I know (without going to the station) if RATP is offering the Anti Pollution tickets?

Tags: public-transport, paris

The Paris public transit system (RATP) offers a reduced fare on days of high pollution, as described here: https://www.ratp.fr/forfait-antipollution ([Google Translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ratp.fr%2Fforfait-antipollution)).

This fare is a very good deal, especially as a tourist!

It has been offered so far every day that I have been visiting, but I only know that because I have been to the train station and seen it advertised. Is there a website where I can look to see whether a particular day is an anti pollution day?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It actually not offered by RATP but by the Paris Region transport authority, Ile-de-France Mobilités, and is available from the participating transport companies, including RATP and SNCF.

When that ticket is available, you’ll find the information on several channels, including [Ile-de-France Mobilités’s Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/IDFmobilites).